# Sinch video call not working in background

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I implemented Sinch video calling in my current app. When the app is in the foreground everything is OK for the incoming call. But when I closed the app and tried to receive an incoming call, it does not show any incoming call. How to do video Sinch calling when application is closed for incoming calls? following is my  FCMMessageReceiverService class.

```
public class FCMMessageReceiverService  extends FirebaseMessagingService implements ServiceConnection {

    Context context;
    private SinchService.SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface;
    HashMap dataHashMap;


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        context = this;
        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushPayload(remoteMessage.getData())) {
            Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
            dataHashMap = (data instanceof HashMap) ? (HashMap) data : new HashMap<>(data);
            if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushPayload(dataHashMap)) {
                getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SinchService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
        } else {
            Intent intent;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                String identifier = remoteMessage.getData().get("identifier");
                if (identifier.equals("0")) {
                    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                }
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }

    }

    public static boolean foregrounded() {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcessInfo = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
        ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(appProcessInfo);
        return (appProcessInfo.importance == appProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND || appProcessInfo.importance == appProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        if (SinchService.class.getName().equals(componentName.getClassName())) {
            mSinchServiceInterface = (SinchService.SinchServiceInterface) iBinder;
        }

        // it starts incoming call activity which does not show incoming caller name and picture
        NotificationResult result = mSinchServiceInterface.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(dataHashMap);
        if (result.isValid() && result.isCall()) {
            CallNotificationResult callResult = result.getCallResult();
            if (callResult.isCallCanceled() || callResult.isTimedOut()) {
                createNotification("Missed Call from : ", callResult.getRemoteUserId());
                return;
            } else {
                if (callResult.isVideoOffered()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, callResult.getRemoteUserId());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else if (result.isValid() && result.isMessage()) {
            //i want to get message content here
            MessageNotificationResult notificationResult = result.getMessageResult();
            createNotification("Received Message from : ", notificationResult.getSenderId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        unbindService(this);
    }

    private void createNotification(String contentTitle, String userId) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(contentTitle).setContentText(userId);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

here is my since service code:

```
public class SinchService extends Service {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "***********";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "***********";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "clientapi.sinch.com";

    public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
    static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

    private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient mSinchClient;
    private String mUserId;
    private PersistedSettings mSettings;


    private StartFailedListener mListener;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSettings = new PersistedSettings(getApplicationContext());
        String userName = mSettings.getUsername();


        if (!userName.isEmpty()) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(this,placecallActvity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            start(userName);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void start(String userName) {
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mSettings.setUsername(userName);
            mUserId = userName;
            mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(userName).applicationKey(APP_KEY).applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();
            mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
            mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);
            mSinchClient.checkManifest();
            mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
            mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
            mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().setRespectNativeCalls(false);
            mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
            mSinchClient.getVideoController().setResizeBehaviour(VideoScalingType.ASPECT_FILL);
            mSinchClient.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
        mSettings.setUsername("");
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mSinchServiceInterface;
    }

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public Call callUserVideo(String userId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUserVideo(userId);
        }

        public NotificationResult relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(final Map payload) {
            if (mSinchClient == null && !mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
                start(mSettings.getUsername());
            } else if (mSinchClient == null && mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {

                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
        }


        public String getUserName() {
            return mUserId;
        }

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            start(userName);
        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public Call getCall(String callId) {
            return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
        }

        public VideoController getVideoController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getVideoController();
        }

        public AudioController getAudioController() {
            if (!isStarted()) {
                return null;
            }
            return mSinchClient.getAudioController();
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {

        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                                                      ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }

    private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private class PersistedSettings {

        private SharedPreferences mStore;

        private static final String PREF_KEY = "Sinch";
        public PersistedSettings(Context context) {
            mStore = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return mStore.getString("Username", "");
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mStore.edit();
            editor.putString("Username", username);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: seriously no one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add FCM to your project

add following code

```
public class SinchService  extends Service {
static final String APP_KEY = "************";
static final String APP_SECRET = "***********";
static final String ENVIRONMENT = "clientapi.sinch.com";
public static final int MESSAGE_PERMISSIONS_NEEDED = 1;
public static final String REQUIRED_PERMISSION = "REQUIRED_PESMISSION";
public static final String MESSENGER = "MESSENGER";
private Messenger messenger;

public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
private SinchClient mSinchClient;
private String mUserId;
private StartFailedListener mListener;
private PersistedSettings mSettings;
private AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
private Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    super.onCreate();
    mSettings = new PersistedSettings(getApplicationContext());
    String userName = mSettings.getUsername();


    if (!userName.isEmpty()) {

       
        start(userName);


    }
    handler = new Handler();

}
private void createClient(String username) {
    mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(username)
            .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
            .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
            .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

    mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
    mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);

    mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
    mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
    mSinchClient.setPushNotificationDisplayName("User " + username);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
        mSinchClient.terminateGracefully();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
private boolean hasUsername() {
    if (mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't start a SinchClient as no username is available!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private void createClientIfNecessary() {
    if (mSinchClient != null)
        return;
    if (!hasUsername()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't create a SinchClient as no username is available!");
    }
    createClient(mSettings.getUsername());
}

private void start(String userName) {
    boolean permissionsGranted = true;
    if (mSinchClient == null) {
        mSettings.setUsername(userName);
        createClient(userName);
    }
    createClientIfNecessary();
    try {
        //mandatory checks
        mSinchClient.checkManifest();
        if (getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            throw new MissingPermissionException(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
    } catch (MissingPermissionException e) {
        permissionsGranted = false;
        if (messenger != null) {
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(REQUIRED_PERMISSION, e.getRequiredPermission());
            message.setData(bundle);
            message.what = MESSAGE_PERMISSIONS_NEEDED;
            try {
                messenger.send(message);
            } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (permissionsGranted) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting SinchClient");
        try {
            mSinchClient.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Can't start SinchClient - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


private void stop() {
    if (mSinchClient != null) {
        mSinchClient.terminateGracefully();
        mSinchClient = null;
    }
}


private boolean isStarted() {
    return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    messenger = intent.getParcelableExtra(MESSENGER);
    return mSinchServiceInterface;
}

public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

    public Call callUserVideo(String userId) {
        return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUserVideo(userId);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return mSettings.getUsername();
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        mSettings.setUsername(username);
    }
    public void retryStartAfterPermissionGranted() {
        SinchService.this.attemptAutoStart();
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return SinchService.this.isStarted();
    }

    public void startClient(String userName) {
        start(userName);
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        stop();
    }

    public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public Call getCall(String callId) {
        return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
    }

    public VideoController getVideoController() {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            return null;
        }
        return mSinchClient.getVideoController();
    }

    public AudioController getAudioController() {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            return null;
        }
        return mSinchClient.getAudioController();
    }

    public NotificationResult relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(final Map payload) {
        if (!hasUsername()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to relay the push notification!");
            return null;
        }
        createClientIfNecessary();
        return mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
    }

}

private void attemptAutoStart() {
}
public interface StartFailedListener {

    void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

    void onStarted();
}

private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onStartFailed(error);
        }
        mSinchClient.terminate();
        mSinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onStarted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
        switch (level) {
            case Log.DEBUG:
                Log.d(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.ERROR:
                Log.e(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.INFO:
                Log.i(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.VERBOSE:
                Log.v(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.WARN:
                Log.w(area, message);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                                                  ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
    }
}

private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

    @Override
    public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onIncomingCall: " + call.getCallId());
        audioPlayer = AudioPlayer.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
        Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, MESSAGE_ID);
        intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
        boolean inForeground = isAppOnForeground(getApplicationContext());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (inForeground) {
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            if (!audioPlayer.isPlayedRingtone()) {
                audioPlayer.playRingtone();
            }
            ((NotificationManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))).notify(MESSAGE_ID, createIncomingCallNotification(call.getRemoteUserId(), intent));
        }
    }
    private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = null;
        if (activityManager != null) {
            appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        }
        if (appProcesses == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int resId) {
        int largeIconWidth = (int) context.getResources()
                .getDimension(R.dimen.height);
        int largeIconHeight = (int) context.getResources()
                .getDimension(R.dimen.height);
        Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(largeIconWidth, largeIconHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, largeIconWidth, largeIconHeight);
        d.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Intent intent, String action) {
        intent.setAction(action);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 111, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }
    @TargetApi(29)
    private Notification createIncomingCallNotification(String userId, Intent fullScreenIntent) {

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 112, fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), FcmListenerService.CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
                        .setContentText(userId)
                        .setLargeIcon(getBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.call_normal))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.call_pressed)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.button_accept, "Answer", getPendingIntent(fullScreenIntent, ACTION_ANSWER))
                        .addAction(R.drawable.button_decline, "Ignore", getPendingIntent(fullScreenIntent, ACTION_IGNORE))
                        .setOngoing(true);

        return builder.build();
    }
}
private class SinchCallListener implements CallListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(Call call) {
        cancelNotification();
        if (audioPlayer != null && audioPlayer.isPlayedRingtone()) {
            audioPlayer.stopRingtone();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Call established");
        if (audioPlayer != null && audioPlayer.isPlayedRingtone()) {
            audioPlayer.stopRingtone();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Call progressing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        // no need to implement for managed push
    }

}
public void cancelNotification() {
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (nMgr != null) {
        nMgr.cancel(MESSAGE_ID);
    }
}
private static class PersistedSettings {
    private SharedPreferences mStore;
    private static final String PREF_KEY = "Sinch";

    public PersistedSettings(Context context) {
        mStore = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return mStore.getString("Username", "");
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mStore.edit();
        editor.putString("Username", username);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

}
and crete FcmListenerService  and add following code

```
public class FcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public static String CHANNEL_ID = "Sinch Push Notification Channel";
private final String PREFERENCE_FILE = "com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.push.shared_preferences";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushPayload(data)) {
        new ServiceConnection() {
            private Map payload;
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                if (payload != null) {
                    SinchService.SinchServiceInterface sinchService = (SinchService.SinchServiceInterface) service;
                    if (sinchService != null) {
                        NotificationResult result = sinchService.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
                        // handle result, e.g. show a notification or similar
                        // here is example for notifying user about missed/canceled call:
                        if (result!=null && result.isValid() && result.isCall()) {
                            CallNotificationResult callResult = result.getCallResult();
                            if (callResult != null && result.getDisplayName() != null) {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString(callResult.getRemoteUserId(), result.getDisplayName());
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                            if (callResult != null && callResult.isCallCanceled()) {
                                String displayName = result.getDisplayName();
                                if (displayName == null) {
                                    displayName = sharedPreferences.getString(callResult.getRemoteUserId(), "n/a");
                                }
                                createMissedCallNotification(!displayName.isEmpty() ? displayName : callResult.getRemoteUserId());
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                    context.deleteSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                payload = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}

            public void relayMessageData(Map<String, String> data) {
                payload = data;
                createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
                getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SinchService.class), this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
        }.relayMessageData(data);
    }
}

private void createNotificationChannel(int importance) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Amar LPG";
        String description = "Incoming call notification";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
private void createMissedCallNotification(String userId) {

    createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingCallScreenActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Missed call from ")
                    .setContentText(userId)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

}

in the incoming call screen add the following code

public class IncomingCallScreenActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
static final String TAG = IncomingCallScreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String mCallId;
private AudioPlayer mAudioPlayer;
public static final String ACTION_ANSWER = "answer";
public static final String ACTION_IGNORE = "ignore";
public static final String EXTRA_ID = "id";
public static int MESSAGE_ID = 14;
private String mAction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call_screen);

    Button answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerButton);
    answer.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
    Button decline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
    decline.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);

    mAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(this);
    mAudioPlayer.playRingtone();
    mCallId = getIntent().getStringExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID);
    mAction = "";
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID) != null) {
            mCallId = getIntent().getStringExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID);
        }
        final int id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
        if (id > 0) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(id);
        }
        mAction = intent.getAction();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
    if (call != null) {
        call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
        TextView remoteUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remoteUser);
        remoteUser.setText(call.getRemoteUserId());

        if (ACTION_ANSWER.equals(mAction)) {
            mAction = "";
            answerClicked();
        } else if (ACTION_IGNORE.equals(mAction)) {
            mAction = "";
            declineClicked();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Started with invalid callId, aborting");
        finish();
    }
}

private void answerClicked() {
    if (mAudioPlayer!=null && mAudioPlayer.isPlayedRingtone()){
        mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
    }

    Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
    if (call != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Answering call");
        call.answer();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallScreenActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, mCallId);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

private void declineClicked() {
    if (mAudioPlayer!=null && mAudioPlayer.isPlayedRingtone()){
        mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
    }
    Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
    if (call != null) {
        call.hangup();
    }
    finish();
}

private class SinchCallListener implements VideoCallListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(Call call) {
        CallEndCause cause = call.getDetails().getEndCause();
        Log.d(TAG, "Call ended, cause: " + cause.toString());
        mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Call established");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallProgressing(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Call progressing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackAdded(Call call) {
        // Display some kind of icon showing it's a video call
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackPaused(Call call) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoTrackResumed(Call call) {

    }
}

private View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.answerButton:
                answerClicked();
                break;
            case R.id.declineButton:
                declineClicked();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

}

in the login activity add the following code.

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements SinchService.StartFailedListener, PushTokenRegistrationCallback, UserRegistrationCallback  {

```
private Button mLoginButton;
private EditText mLoginName;
private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
private String mUserId;
private long mSigningSequence = 1;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},100);
    }

   
    mLoginName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginName);
    mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    mLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginClicked();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    mLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
    getSinchServiceInterface().setStartListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mSpinner != null) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStartFailed(SinchError error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (mSpinner != null) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();
    }
}


@Override
public void onStarted() {
    openPlaceCallActivity();
}


private void loginClicked() {
    String userName = mLoginName.getText().toString();

    if (userName.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted()) {
        getSinchServiceInterface().startClient(userName);
        showSpinner();
    } else {
        openPlaceCallActivity();
    }
    mUserId = userName;
    UserController uc = Sinch.getUserControllerBuilder()
            .context(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
            .userId(mUserId)
            .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT)
            .build();
    uc.registerUser(this, this);
}




private void openPlaceCallActivity() {
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, PlaceCallActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainActivity);
    finish();
}

private void showSpinner() {
    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mSpinner.setTitle("Logging in");
    mSpinner.setMessage("Please wait...");
    mSpinner.show();
}
private void dismissSpinner() {
    if (mSpinner != null) {
        mSpinner.dismiss();
        mSpinner = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void tokenRegistered() {
    dismissSpinner();
    startClientAndOpenPlaceCallActivity();

}

private void startClientAndOpenPlaceCallActivity() {
    // start Sinch Client, it'll result onStarted() callback from where the place call activity will be started
    if (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted()) {
        getSinchServiceInterface().startClient("");
        showSpinner();
    }
}

@Override
public void tokenRegistrationFailed(SinchError sinchError) {
    dismissSpinner();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Push token registration failed - incoming calls can't be received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onCredentialsRequired(ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
    String toSign = mUserId + APP_KEY + mSigningSequence + APP_SECRET;
    String signature;
    MessageDigest messageDigest;
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        signature = Base64.encodeToString(hash, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }

    clientRegistration.register(signature, mSigningSequence++);

}

@Override
public void onUserRegistered() {

}

@Override
public void onUserRegistrationFailed(SinchError sinchError) {
    dismissSpinner();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Registration failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

on our SDK package you will find under the Samples folder multiple sample files, the one called sinch-rtc-sample-video-push does what you wnat.
You should also check our docs here:
https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-android-push-notifications

Best regards

[image: Android Sample Apps]